# using bubble sort on object containing list of tuples

Tags: python, object, bubble-sort

im attempting to bubble sort the countries by integers below. ive tested the bubble sort on a list so know it works, but i can not get it to work when the list of tuples is in an object, which is the point of the exercise im trying to complete. I know it is something to do with attempting to use incorrect requests on an object but can not seem to figure out what. This is the error i get.

**if lst[i][1] < lst[i + 1][1]:
TypeError: 'LinkedList' object is not subscriptable**

'''

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.label = data[0][0]
        self.value = data[0][1]
        self.tail = None if (len(data) == 1) else LinkedList(data[1:])

    def leng(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def bubble_sort(self, lst):
        self.lst = LinkedList(self.data)

        for mx in range(lst.leng() - 1, -1, -1):
            swapped = False
            for i in range(mx):
                if lst[i][1] < lst[i + 1][1]:
                   lst[i], lst[i + 1] = lst[i + 1], lst[i]
                   swapped = True
            if not swapped:
                break 
countries = LinkedList([("Ukraine",41879904),("Brunei",442400),("Christmas Island (Australia)",1928),("Mauritius",1265985),("Lesotho",2007201),("Guatemala",16604026)
newlst = countries
countries.bubble_sort(newlst
```

'''

Comment: @edd so i should add a __getitem__ method in my class to be able to use index on the object?

Answer (score 0):

`subscriptable` complains about `[1]` notation on the class object that didn't implement that "access" method.

What happens is, the type `list` implements a special dundermethod, `__getitem__` , that allows you to reference its items with `my_list[1]`.
So, if that's how you want to access your field, you can briefly read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).